# Promise is not getting returned in the redux thunk

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am new to `react-redux`. Here what I am doing is that,

I have an action that is like

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch ({
      type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
      payload: activePage
    });
  }
}
```

Now, in my container, I want to call an action which will get called after this so,

```
handlePageChange = (pageNumber) => {
    this.props.updateActivePage(pageNumber).then(() => {
      this.props.fetchUserJd(this.props.activePage);
    })
  }



case UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE:  {
      console.log("action payload", action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        activePage: action.payload
      }
    }
```

So, Here I am trying to use `then` but I am getting an error that `Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.updateActivePage(...).then is not a function`

So what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: `updateActivePage` returns a function, not a promise.

Comment: okay . So How can I do this thing ?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it ? Please check when it is being called. And where exactly you have defined `updateActivePage`.

Comment: And yes also update your question and add some more code.

Comment: Actually the function is also getting called I tried console log in the updateActivePage then it is printing the console value

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging

Comment: I have added the reducer code as well. It is calling the reducer as well.. and after that I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

You are fundamentally misusing redux-thunk. The intended use for this library is to dispatch an action creator (in this case, `updateActivePage`), which returns a function that gets invoked with state params. You should be dispatching `updateActivePage` since this is your thunk. Also, this is the function which should contain your computation, which should then posit the results into state. It appears that you are calling this function directly, and for some reason expect it to return a promise, and then somehow doing some computation. You should re-visit the thunk docs.

Comment: What I want to do is that call a function which is given in question. And this function is going to update the state value through reducer and then that updated value will be a param for the next function .So, that is why I need then there because If I dont use it then the previous value is getting  as a param to the next function

Comment: I mean, you might be looking to do `dispatch(updateActivePage()).then( ... )` since the dispatcher returns a promise

Answer (score 0):

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return dispatch ({
      type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
      payload: activePage
    });
  }
}
```

dispatch is not a promise, It just a function.

```
export const updateActivePage = (activePage) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      dispatch ({
        type: UPDATE_ACTIVEPAGE,
        payload: activePage
      });
      res(true);
    })
  }
}
```

Can you try returning promise like I mentioned above?

Comment: this worked for me. Thanks :-) This is the right way to do ?

Comment: Ideally redux thunk is used to handle async events. But yours is not a async event, But If you want to get the callback from reducer, Then we can return a promise like this.